# What jQuery selector can I use to select only my active custom checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given the following HTML:

```
 <div class="clearfix">
    <a class="custom-checkbox"></a>
    <span class="custom-checkbox-text">Text 1</span>
</div>
 <div class="clearfix">
    <a class="custom-checkbox active"></a>
    <span class="custom-checkbox-text">Text 2</span>
</div>
 <div class="clearfix">
    <a class="custom-checkbox active"></a>
    <span class="custom-checkbox-text">Text 3</span>
</div>
```

I would like a selector that return an array of text items where the sibling anchor link is of class "active". By way of example, I would like the query to return ["Text 2", "Text 3"] for the above HTML. I know I can do this using JavaScript and if/else but is there a "clever" way to do this using jQuery selectors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Next Adjacent Selector](http://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-selector/) along with [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to create the desired array as below

```
var array = $('.custom-checkbox.active + .custom-checkbox-text').map(function(){
    return $.trim($(this).text())
}).get()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/PGKvU/)